# How to fetch the value of a key for all the index in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to access cart.item for all the index to get the values from products collection to get the current price of the product.

```
 const CartSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    cart: [
        {
        item: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'product'
        },
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            default: 1
        },
        image: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
],
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    modifiedOn: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
},
{ 
    timestamps: true 
});
```

This is how my cart schema looks. And I want to access all the **cart.item** in the array like (obviously it's not done like this). I want to join it with Product collection to get the current price of the items in the cart to calculate the sum and return total. The local field in the cart item is **cart.item** and the foreign field is **_id** in the product schema

```
const ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true
    },
    inStock: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

const Products = mongoose.model('product', ProductSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to populate the cart item
here's how:

in your find() function

> Cart.find({}).populate('cart.item'))